# SolR incorrecly highlights date in snippet

Tags: solr

When querying SolR with a date SolR will actually highlight stuff from the text field where it matches elements from the date, typically year.

So a query like:

```
q=text:(John)++AND+date:[2010-01-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2019-12-31T23:59:59Z]&hl=true
```

Will return snippets like:

```
blabla bla bla <em>2011</em> bla bla blabla
```

As well as snippets where 'John' is properly highlighted. In all cases, 'John' does appear in the text, it is simple not in the snippet part.

I've tried adding `hl.fl=text` but that changes nothing.

How can I prevent dates in the text snippets from ever being highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

Use `fq` for the `date` term.

`q=text:(John)&fq=date:[2010-01-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2019-12-31T23:59:59Z]&hl=true`